# Using Bluetooth logo in animation

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-animation

I started to think is it allowed to put Bluetooth logo like this

[image]

in my Android application? It would be used for scanning animation while bluetooth devices are being discovered.

[image]

From [this](https://www.bluetooth.com/develop-with-bluetooth/marketing-branding/brand-guide-logos) document I understood that I can't use logo like this

[image]

or this

[image]

but how about logo in my animation?

Comment: From which document ? There is no link to any document .

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about legal issue not programming.

Comment: Maybe you are right, i'll post this later on law.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the answer to my question.

> **Figure mark used on electronic displays**
>
> Solely for the display of the Bluetooth trademarks on an electronic
> display, the licensee may modify the color of the Runic B component of
> the Bluetooth marks as follows. If the Bluetooth marks are used on a
> solid color display, the color of the Runic B may match the color of
> the display background. If the Bluetooth marks are used on a
> multi-colored or patterned background and the licensee chooses not to
> use the color blue for the Runic B, the Runic B must be displayed in
> solid green, red, gray, or black provided, however, that the
> back-light illuminating the respective Bluetooth marks is blue. If,
> for purposes of maintaining consistency on electronic display screens
> or because of the nature of the electronic display, the licensee would
> like to use a slightly modified figure mark or to modify the
> background of the figure mark (e.g., to apply gradation or mirror
> effects, or to apply a different color, or to use a semi- transparent
> background), express approval from Bluetooth SIG must be obtained
> prior to such use.
>
> Please contact brand.manager@bluetooth.com for any such requests or
> questions. Please note that exceptions will only be considered for
> uses of the figure mark on electronic displays;

[image]

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I am not sure! but if you follow the link to 
https://commons.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Bluetooth.svg you'll find the information:

> This image of simple geometry is ineligible for copyright and therefore in the public domain, because it consists entirely of information that is common property and contains no original authorship.

I think this can basically be applied to your image, but no guarantee! Your logo contains no trademark sign, but you should check the licence of your image source.

Comment: Thanks you very much for answering, I got my image from [here](https://material.io/icons/#ic_bluetooth)